# Windows 8 , Your Pc ran into problemlem and needs to restart

Tags: windows-8, bsod

I have Hp laptop with Windows 8, After trying to install Norton, it does not boot and restarts itself.

I tried to go to HP recovery by pressing F11 but gives me same error and restarts.

Error is System_Thread_exception__not_handled iaStor.sys

I havent create windows 8 media and right not i cannot access windows to create one.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: iaStor.sys = Intel driver. Install this one: https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&ProdId=2101&DwnldID=23496

Comment: You should use `BlueScreenViewer` so we can have additional details of what drivers were loaded when you recieved this error

Answer (score 1):

`System Thread Exception Not Handled` error mostly arises due to incompatible software or old graphics card drivers. To fix this, you would have to restart PC in safe mode and uninstall the problematic software or driver. 
 When system restarts, press **F8** button continuously to display the **Advanced Boot Options**  and select **Safe Mode**. Thereafter, you'd have to log into window 8 system with most priviliged account to go to desktop. From there, go to **Control Panel** and uninstall problematic Norton software. Also, make sure you're using the latest version of graphic driver